# SVG DOM vs. CSS in browser

Tags: dom, browser, svg

I plan a map (simplified, no source from reality, just a fantasy image) with some points where the user may click and do actions in them.

The first thought I had is drawing it in an SVG editor, add `class` and `data-id` to the points and attach a DOM-event to them. But I have concerns about browser compatibility about it.

The second idea would be defining it point for point in CSS, model the shapes out etc. Sounds like a lot of work.

So what would be the preferred way to implement this?

Comment: What would you prefer, to do a lot of work or have less browser compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a small map and upload it to http://www.irunmywebsite.com/raphael/SVGTOHTML_LIVE.php 
If you go to the JavaScript it generates you will see that mouseover click and mouseout events have already Bren coded

The JavaScript is located by following the red line when the conversion finishes.

Then you can spend all day in Inkscape and iterate with the converter

Excuse spelling iPod sometimes prefers spelling things wrong...